# НЕ — отдельно/слитно?

Tags: частица-не

> Определить количество невыполненных или не надлежаще выполненных
>   операций.

Здесь *не* относится к *выполненных* (прич.), у которого есть зависимое слово *надлежаще*, или — к *надлежаще*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все требовавшие выполнения операции можно разделить на три группы:

1. Надлежаще выполненные;
2. Ненадлежаще выполненные;
3. Невыполненные.

**Не надлежаще выполненные** = ненадлежаще выполненные + невыполненные.

Comment: К сожалению, в ответе отсутствует вывод. А он, по-моему, таков: поскольку  *невыполненные* уже упомянуты, то логично предположить, что второй элемент — *ненадлежаще выполненные*.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что **не** относится к "надлежаще", иначе предложение просто не имеет смысла.
[Определить количество невыполненных или (не) выполненных операций.]

В орфографическом словаре:
[ненадлежаще](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-ortho-term-51390.htm) — наречие; синонимично словам *несоответственно, неподобающе, неразумно.*

В орфографическом словаре-справочнике:
[ненадлежаще исполненный](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/51142/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5).
Исполненный = выполненный; выполненный (как? каким образом?) ненадлежаще.

*Определить количество невыполненных или **ненадлежаще** выполненных операций.*

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **Определить количество невыполненных или ненадлежаще (как?) выполненных операций.**

Собственного говоря, варианты могут быть такими: ***выполненный и невыполненный; надлежаще выполненный и ненадлежаще выполненный.***

Наречия ***надлежаще/ненадлежаще*** оценивают правильность выполненной работы.

В предложении использовано наречие ***ненадлежаще***, здесь НЕ — это приставка со слитным написанием.

НАДЛЕЖАЩИЙ,  Такой, какой следует; должный, соответствующий. Принять н. вид.

Схема образования наречия: ***надлежащий — ненадлежащий — ненадлежаще.***

**Примеры:**

1)  Удовлетворение требований, предусмотренных пунктами 1, 2 и 3 настоящей статьи, не освобождает сторону, не исполнившую или **ненадлежаще исполнившую** обязательство, от возмещения иных убытков, причиненных другой стороне, на основании статьи 15 настоящего Кодекса. [Гражданский кодекс Российской Федерации. Часть вторая (1995) // , 2004]

2) Он заклеил концы суровой нити бумажным квадратиком, оттиснул печать...отложил дело на край стола, где уже лежали шесть законченных и **надлежаще оформленных.** [Даниил Корецкий. Менты не ангелы, но… (2011)]